# Mystery branch in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I'm a little new to using Mercurial but so far I really like it.  Recently though I've noticed I've managed to create a branch somehow, but I'm not sure how it's happened.  Now when I do:

```
hg branches
```

I get:

```
default                      167:e1ca9e2a5efc
```

With the second one appearing to update at each commit.  What could have happened here, and can I get rid of it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not created a branch, that's the **default branch** of your repository, and the second part is just a *reference* to the entry of your repository corresponding to that branch, as it's the default one, it's updated to the last commit always.

With `hg branch` you can see the **current** branch name, if you try, you will see that you are working on the **default branch**. You can use `hg branch BRANCH_NAME` to **change** to branch **BRANC_NAME**.